Call to Trace.Fail() end up always breaking code execution
When using Trace.Fail() method, the code execution (either in debug or release) will always halt at this line (226)

if (AutoFlush) listener.Flush();

in TraceInternal.Fail() method.
It behave just like if there were a breakpoint at this line but it is not my code (it is one of the built-in System.Diagnostics classes).
I guess this is related to the change I made that was to allow debugger to step into other assembly code, if ever debug symbol were available, in order to ease my library debugging.
Am I missing something here ?

This is normal behavior, the debugger automatically breaks the execution flow when Trace.Fail() is called. This is because the Trace.Fail() method triggers a debugger break, which is often used to provide notification when a problem is detected at runtime. The official documentation does not specify this, but it is indeed the default behavior. If you need to log information without interrupting program execution and use Trace.Fail(), you need to add code before setting up a listener for Trace output: Trace.Listeners.Clear();

I Tried that since I suspected it might be related, but instead of breaking into TraceInternal.Fail() method, it break at Trace.Fail() method call in my code (with a dark green arrow in visual studio). So it doesn't change that my execution flow is stopped each time I call Trace.Fail(). I don't know why.

This is normal behavior, the debugger automatically breaks execution flow when Trace.Fail() is called. This is because the Trace.Fail() method triggers a debugger break, which is usually used to provide notification when a problem is detected at runtime. If you need to log information and use Trace.Fail() without interrupting program execution, you need to add the code before setting listeners for Trace output: Trace.Listeners.Clear();

Good to know, I didn't found any intel about that default behavior of breaking execution flow in the documentation  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=net-8.0 (or I missed it ?). So yeah instead I wrote my own method instead of Trace.Fail() to display stackTrace to debug output witch was what I was looking for in a first place.

The official documentation does not specify this, but its default behavior is indeed like this. If you accept this situation, I will modify my reply above and you can mark it as the answer. If you do not accept this situation, I suggest you post your own solution and mark it as the answer, so that people with the same problem can find the solution faster.

Yep you can modify your answer to say it is the, though undocumented, normal behavior of Trace.Fail(). That answer my question.

Thanks, I've edited the above, you can mark this as the answer if that's ok.
